# Calculating significant number (or greatest common prefix)

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

I am trying to work out an algorithm that can determine the greatest common prefix for a given number range. I have an algorithm that works for the simplest cases. but I am not happy with it, and it falls apart on the more difficult case(s).

The idea is that for a given number range, print out the prefixes that will match all numbers, with a given length. For example, if we had 1 with a length of 3 it would match all numbers between 100 - 199.

Lengths are not dealt with or addressed in the code at all, just prefixes.

Code with samples below. The third case doesn't work at all. Start is expected to always be less than end, although there isn't an explicit check for that at the moment.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def calc_sig_num(start, end):
    print("Start {} End {}".format(start, end))
    while start[-1] == "0" and end[-1] == "9":
        start = start[:-1]
        end = end[:-1]

    start = int(start)
    end = int(end)

    diff = end - start

    ones_removed = 0
    keep = True
    while True:
        if keep:
            print(start + diff)
        if diff == 0:
            break
        elif (start + diff) % 10 == 0:
            if ones_removed:
                keep = False
                ones_removed = 0
            else:
                start //= 10
                diff //= 10
        else:
            diff -= 1
            ones_removed += 1
            keep = True
    print()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    calc_sig_num("4929310000", "4929319999")
    calc_sig_num("4929312000", "4929312511")
    calc_sig_num("8666361784", "8666362423")

"""
expected ouput

Start 4929310000 End 4929319999
492931

Start 4929312000 End 4929312511
4929312511
4929312510
492931250
49293124
49293123
49293122
49293121
49293120

Start 8666361784 End 8666362423
8666362423
8666362422
8666362421
8666362420
866636241
866636240
86663623
86663622
86663621
86663620
86663619
86663618
866636179
8666361789
8666361788
8666361787
8666361786
8666361785
8666361784
"""
```

Comment: `os.path.commonprefix(["4929310000", "4929319999"])` -> `'492931'`

Comment: That works for the simplest case, but does not do what I am trying to do, which is generate greatest common prefix for the range of start and end. For the first case, the range is quite limited, and is easy to calculate the greatest common prefix.

Comment: I do not understand. Could you show an example where `os.path.commonprefix()` fails?

Comment: Did you see the expected output at the end of the code?

Comment: yes. It looks like failed output from your broken code.

Comment: It is "expected output" or desired output. The code produces the first two sets correctly, but not the third.

Comment: I do not understand the definition for "greatest common prefix" that you use.

Comment: Okay. Perhaps Greatest Common Prefix is not the correct description.

Comment: os.path.commonprefix(["8666361784", "8666362423"]) -> '866636' is wrong, for what I am trying to do. 

It suggests that any number that starts with 866636 falls within the range "8666361784", "8666362423", which is not true.

Comment: It suggests that all numbers in the range `8666361784-8666362423` start with `866636` that is correct. What you suggest is that all numbers in the range are the answer. Do you want to minimize the number of allowed prefixes that cover all numbers in the range and only the numbers in the range?

Comment: According to the examples, I think what he want is minimize the number of allowed prefixes that cover all numbers in the range and only the numbers in the range

Comment: This looks like the problem "Billing Tables" from [NEERC 2006](http://neerc.ifmo.ru/past/2006.html). If you want, you can have a look at my [C++ solution](http://pastie.org/8902349#) for the problem, but I doubt you will have much fun with it. It must be among the worst programs I've written in my life

Comment: Exactly right, @gloompisces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion is your friend:

```
import os
def calc_sig_num(a, b):
    lcp = os.path.commonprefix([a,b])
    a, b = a[len(lcp):], b[len(lcp):]       # we now have a[0] < b[0]
    if a == "0"*len(a) and b == "9"*len(b): # base case, range is X00.. - X99..
        yield lcp
        return
    da, db = int(a[0]), int(b[0])
    size = len(a) - 1
    for d in range(da, db + 1):  # we iterate over 1 digit prefix extensions
        suffixes = calc_sig_num(a[1:] if d == da else "0"*size,
                                b[1:] if d == db else "9"*size)
        for suffix in suffixes:
            yield lcp + str(d) + suffix
```

It's a quick and dirty implementation, so bear with me. I like to think it has a certain elegance though ;) And it should definitely illustrate the concept.

Comment: Perfect.

For those following at home, if you want this to work in Python 3, replace "xrange" with "range", and be sure to "import os"